# Not able to open permission page when using gmail outh2 using domain name but it works fine while using localhost VS 2017

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

I am new user of the outh2 gmail api. When i created the Web Api and tried to run I am able to redirect to gmail permission page on button click. 
But after hosting it in iis and creating a domain I am not able to redirect to permission page of gmail.

Here is the code part:

```
private GmailService GmailServices()          {    
 UserCredential credential;    
 GmailService service = new GmailService();
 string GmailCredentialLocation = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~\\GmailClientDetails.json");
 using (var stream =
             new FileStream(GmailCredentialLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    UserId,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
                    ).Result;
            }
            service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            SetUserSub(UserId);
            SendMail();
        }
        return service;
    }
```

While running on the domain i am not getting any error even tried debugging once it reach to

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(   
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    UserId,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

this code part it do backs to the domain and the domain buffering keeps on going

Any Suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer), when you create your `OAuth client ID` on the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) in the API Console for a `Web application` type (*to get a `client_secret.json` file*)

Please note that:

> Applications that use languages and frameworks like PHP, Java, Python,
>   Ruby, and **.NET must specify authorized redirect URIs**. The redirect
>   URIs are the endpoints to which the OAuth 2.0 server can send
>   responses.

I expect that you setup intialy your credentials with localhost only - as authorized redirect URIs - so if you **add your domain URIs** to the authorized redirect URIs and **specify URIs that refer to your domain**, then **regenerate your *`client_secret.json`*** it will work.

Comment: I have added "http://<domain>" and "https://<domain> in Authorised JavaScript origins  and for Authorised redirect URIs i have added "http://<domain>/signin-google,http://<domain>/signin-google/,http://<domain>/authorize ,http://<domain>/authorize/,http://<domain>/thankyou,http://<domain>/thankyou,https://<domain>/signin-google,https://<domain>/signin-google/,https://<domain>/authorize ,https://<domain>/authorize/,https://<domain>/thankyou,https://<domain>/thankyou " and saved the new json but still no luck. Also is SSL certificate must. I have just got a domin for my static/public ip.

Comment: Are you sure that you select the "web application" type ? You may also double check that IIS allow external redirection ? Does IIS change any request header when redirect ? Did you try to add (only) http://<domain>/ and https://<domain>/  in Authorised redirect URIs ?

Comment: In your comment: "Javascript origins", do you setup your credentials for "Javascript" or "web application" ?

Comment: Its a web application and i removed all the "Javascript origins" and just kept the urls at "redirect url" section. I tried  to add (only) http://<domain>/ and https://<domain>/ still no luck :(

Comment: "You may also double check that IIS allow external redirection ? Does IIS change any request header when redirect ? " any link i can read to check these things properly will be a great help.